# MongoDB: $log operator returns wrong values with NumberDecimal type

Tags: mongodb

The $log aggregation arithemetic operator seems to return the wrong values in certain cases.

An example query-

```
{$log: [5.42, 23.23] # Returns 0.537.... (Correct Answer)
```

While-

```
{$log: [5.42, NumberDecimal(23.23)] # Returns NumberDecimal(0.072....) (Incorrect Answer)
```